# troubleshooting steps for nonworking netbook

Tags: troubleshooting, netbook

I've got an old Acer AspireOne that's been sitting around with a power connector issue for a couple of years. I finally bought a new whip for it and now it's got power, but the netbook itself won't boot. What sort of stpes shold I take to try to figure out what's wrong? Complicating the issue is thatthe screen is badly damaged; I'm mostly trying to ascertain whether or not this baby's worth buying a new screen for.  Here's what I know so far:

- System powers up and the screen glows
- I can't hear a POST beep, but I don't recall if I always heard one or not
- Definitely no windows startup sounds
- keyboard connection is ok; when I use the function keys for screen brightness they do what they're supposed to do
- connecting the VGA output to another monitor (well, an LCD tv) doesn't show any data

Is there any hope to be had here, or are the possibilities so broad that I may as well give up now?

Comment: cori: The screen is the second most expensive part on a laptop, its not worth the gamble. I assume there is no external monitor port?

Comment: there is (VGA), but when connected to an lcd-tv-as-monitor the monitor complains of no data.

Comment: Do you see any kind of BIOS boot screen? Does anything other than the backlight on the screen light up?

Comment: not so far as I can tell - just the backlight, but as I said, the screen's in pretty bad shape: a crack low-down that crosses the 75-80% of the screen. Above that is just white, below and to one side just black.

Comment: I would try a regular PC monitor rather than a TV if you can.